# Start a WPF animation when a property on another control has changed

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF control that I want to animate, based on the value of a property IsInteracting defined on the containing UserControl (named "UserControl"). I have the following style defined in the UserControl, with the animation targeting a Grid also defined in the UserControl.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value=""></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsInteracting" Value="True" SourceName="UserControl">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=ControlGrid}"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                >
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="1"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This isn't working as the name "UserControl" isn't recognised. I believe there are scoping issues which prevent the referencing of elements outside of the style?

How do I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=IsInteracting}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>                            
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the style is not correct place to use some another (outer) control trigger to start the animation. I suggest you to look at the next solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274516/visibility-of-one-user-control-to-another-user-control/33277747#33277747), there was a similar problem.

I'll be glad to help if you will have a problem with code.
Regards.